# Highstock - Can't update using value from file, data type?

Tags: variables, types, highcharts, updating

I'm still pretty new to JS, JQuery and Highcharts.

From the "dynamic-update" example in HighStock:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var series = this.series[0];
            var y = 1;
            setInterval(function() {
                var x = (new Date()).getTime();
                $.get('get_most_recent_point_from_database.php',function(data){
                alert( data);
                var y = data;
                // y = 10;
                alert( y);
                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
},
```

"get_most_recent_point_from_database.php" produces an integer.

The alerts show the integer, but series.addPoint doesn't add the integer to the chart.  The chart just goes blank.

The "y = 10;" (commented out in the code) will update the chart with 10.

I set y to integer by "var y = 1;" thinking that might help.

Any thoughts?  I can put it all in JSFiddle if it helps.

THE FIX ======================

```
    setInterval(function() {

     var x = (new Date()).getTime(), y;

     $.get('get_most_recent_point_from_database.php',function(data){

     y = parseFloat(data).toFixed(1);

     series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);

    });

  }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How your data looks like? probably it is string, so try to convert it by parseFloat(data) (if it is single point) or use json_encode() in php. (All depends how your php file looks like)

Comment: That's It! - parseFloat(data) did it.  It is a single point, just a number.  It guess it makes sense it was being read as a string.  Thank you sir.